# executing 2 file watchers on the same job on talend

Tags: parallel-processing, automation, etl, talend

I have 2 file watchers on the same job on talend. I want both of them to run on the same time. Right now what is happening is that only one file checks its corresponding directory. Its all on the same job design, can I run them on parallel ?

Comment: Can you please post an image of your job?

Comment: if tParallelize component is available you could use it

Comment: tParallelize is not on the free version correct me if im wrong